# nodejs: atomic file replace operation, trigger only one time some watchers

Tags: javascript, node.js, watch

I have two kinds of processes. One shall write a file, the others shall read it, if it is changed.

I found [`fs.watch`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) to get the reading processes informed, if they have to reload the file.

To write the file, I could use [`fs.writeFile`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback).

But I am not sure, if this is a atomic replace. Will `watch` trigged several times, if the file is large?

What would be the correct way, to get this as atomic operation?

FYI: On the target system runs Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some test I got this results:

`fs.watch` fires the `change` event multiple times while large file is written. The problem is, you can not see, which will be the last one to figure out, that the write operation has finished.

**The solution** is: Write a temp file in the same directory and than use `link` and `unlink` to replace the old file with the new one.

In code it could look like this:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var consts = require('constants');

/**
 * write given date in temp file and replace the dstpath with that.
 *
 * @author Tobias Lindig
 * 
 * @param  {string} dstpath destination path
 * @param  {string} data    [description]
 *
 * @throws {Error} If fs operations failed.
 */
function atomicWrite(dstpath, data) {
    // build a unique temp path
    var dir = path.dirname(dstpath);
    var tempName = [
        'temp',
        process.pid,
        (Math.random() * 0x1000000000).toString(36),
        new Date().getTime()
    ].join('-');
    var tempPath = path.join(dir, tempName);

    var tempOptions = {
        encoding: 'utf8',
        mode: 420, // aka  0644 in Octal
        flags: consts.O_CREAT | consts.O_TRUNC | consts.O_RDWR | consts.O_EXCL
    };

    //local function to remove temp file
    var fn_removeTempFileSync = function() {
        try {
            fs.unlinkSync(tempPath);
        } catch (ex) {
            // ignore fail, may be file was not created.
        }
    };

    try {
        fs.writeFileSync(tempPath, data, tempOptions);

        // remove possible old version of file
        // because fs.link can not overwrite existing dstpath.
        if (fs.existsSync(dstpath)) {
            fs.unlinkSync(dstpath);
        }

        //copy temp file to destination path
        fs.linkSync(tempPath, dstpath);

        fn_removeTempFileSync();
    } catch (ex) {
        fn_removeTempFileSync();
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Now `fs.watch` fires the event `change` for the file ("dstpath") only one time.

That the theory.

But in the real world, unfortunately the `change` event was not triggered in every case, some time it missed. So I have watch the `rename` event too.

The event will come in this order:

`rename` // ever, if file was deleted
`rename` // ever, file was created
`change` // some times, file was created

To read the file only one time, I member the `mtime` of file and read only, if it was different.